# Set dirty bit to 1 when we have a miss write?

Tags: caching

When we are writing into cache and it is a miss do we have to set the dirty bit to 1 or does it not make a difference since we have to pull it in from Ram anyways.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: IMHO, you can ignore, because next db hit would set the value in cache

Comment: @Saravanan So there is no rule to follow? I'm not sure if this is right but I remember reading/hearing that for write-back cache you always set the dirty bit to 1 when you write...

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember from school, if you are using write-back, you usually allocate the block in cache and read the value from memory, then edit it and mark it dirty.
On substitution the dirty block is actually written in memory.